# how to setup bindable checkbox value automatically changed to male/female

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, detailsview

I'm using detailsview in asp.net. I have gender field. when this field checked, checkbox text automatically changed to 'male', otherwise 'female'. 
How can i do?
How to setup checkbox to this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I hope you aren't actually doing this, the following will accomplish it:

```
protected void chkSex_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkSex = (CheckBox)sender;
    chkSex.Text = SexString(chkSex.Checked);
}
protected string SexString(bool sex)
{
    return sex ? "Male" : "Female";
}
```

And the markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" 
            Checked='<%# Eval("Sex") %>'
            OnCheckedChanged="chkSex_CheckedChanged" 
            AutoPostBack="true" 
            Text='<%# SexString((bool)Eval("Sex")) %>'/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some simple javascript.

Mark Up

```
<label id="sexLabel" for="sexCheckBox">Male</label>
<input id="sexCheckBox" type="checkbox" onclick="sexClick(this);" />
```

Code

```
function sexClick(checkbox) {
    document.getElementById('sexLabel').innerHTML = (checkbox.checked) ? 'Female' : 'Male';     
}
```

**jQuery**

Mark Up

```
<label id="sexLabel" for="sexCheckBox">Male</label>
<input id="sexCheckBox" type="checkbox" />
```

Code

```
$(function() {
    $('#sexCheckBox').click(function() {
        $('#sexLabel').text((checkbox.checked) ? 'Female' : 'Male');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the column or property name is Sex and is true if sex is male. Use this in markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSex" Text='<%# GetText((bool)Eval("Sex"))%>' 
         Checked='<%# Eval("Sex")%>' />
```

write this method in code-behind:

```
protected static object GetText(bool b)
{
    return b ? "Male" : "Female";
}
```